# Facing error on file Upload using angular and php

Tags: php, angularjs

I am uploading xls file from angularjs and capturing on php, but temp_name and size is blank

Angular js

```
$scope.uploadstock = function ($event) {

    if (typeof $event != "undefined") {
        $scope.uploads.user_file = $event.target.files[0];
    }
    $scope.stock_upload_loading = true;
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("user_file", $scope.uploads.user_file);
    fd.append("data_source", $event.target.attributes.data_source.value);
    fd.append("saccount", $scope.firstAccId.id);

    FileUpload.getData(fd, bulk_stock_upload + "uploaduserfile").then(function (result) {
            result = result.data;
        if (result.code === 200) {
            $scope.handleUploadResponse(result);
            } else {
            if (result.code === 703 || result.code === 705
                || result.code === 702 || result.code === 704
                || result.code === 707 || result.code === 706
                || result.code === 708 || result.code === 701
                || result.code === 412
            ) {
                if (result.message === 'Invalid File Format') {
                    clevertap.event.push("Errors", {
                        "Type": "Incorrectfileformat",
                    });


                }


                }
            }
                $scope.fileerr = result.message;
            }
            $scope.stock_upload_loading = false;  
    });

};
```

PHP

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Getting below

```
Array
(
    [user_file] => Array
        (
            [name] => stocks.xls
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 6
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Because of missing tmp_name and size is 0 I m unable to upload file
Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code 6 (UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR) which temp folder to upload files on server is not exists. This issue is not coming from angular. You need to create temporary folder to upload files on server. Just fix your settings of *.ini files. Check the below links for more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Fix your settings..

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: Oho! Thanks my dear friend! It worked, i was solving this since yesterday. Grateful to you.

Comment: Cheers! Can you please accept the answer if it works for you :)